# Why is casting not done after the variable?

Tags: c#, java, language-design

Isn't it more logical to have `animal(Elephant).UseTrunk()` ? This way you don't have to clutter your code with all these extra parantheses like in `((Elephant)animal).UseTrunk()`

Is this for historic reasons? would it interfere with other syntax? or am I missing something else?

I have an almost religious respect for the clean and pureness of the C# syntax and language, but the casting syntax always feels a bit like the black sheep to me.

PS. I do know about (animal as Elephant).UseTrunk(), but that's not the question :) besides that it is in theory a workaround - breaking the idea of the clean and pureness of the language.

Comment: This comes from earlier times than C#...

Comment: If Elephant is class, you can put it (in C#) like (animal as Elephant).UseTrunk();

Comment: There are even more "black sheeps" in both C# and Java, and not only in syntax... you either deal with it, or try to raise money using a different language(s).

Comment: @Sarge Borsch I don't think curiosity about the reasons **why** ever made the world a worse place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the syntax you suggest is ambiguous! Since `dot` is a primary operator in c#, it has the highest precedence, so without using parenthesis how do you parse the `animal(Elephant).UseTrunk()`? As you said, `UseTrunk()` should be applied for `animal(Elephant)` rather than `(Elephant)` and since `dot` has the higher precedence it will produce some sort of ambiguity. But if you wanna lower the precedence of `dot` then as a language designer, you'll face much more complications. Besides, with that kind of syntax, how would you handle method calls? How would you distinguish method call from cast operator? So practically the best way is to use extra pairs of parenthesis to control the situation.

Comment: Instead of lowering the precedence of the dot, you could of course just up the precedence of the cast. Same thing, but sounds a lot less dramatic ;) but anyway interesting point!

Comment: @DirkBoer as I said, with lowering the precedence of [dot] you'll face some difficulties, besides as I told in the answer (I've added some extra thins to it), how do you handle method calls? Since with that format the method call and cast operators are syntactically same. All I want to say is, with that kind of syntax, probably the language designer would face much more complications, like more complex *Grammer* and *parse*. Hope this clarified my answer.

Comment: 1. The point about `UseTrunk` being applied to the expression in parenthesis is wrong, because `animal(Elephant)` is a variation of a method call which works as intended. 2. Distinguishing method calls and type casts can be done contextually, depending on the expression in parenthesis. There are a lot of contextual stuff in C# grammar, it allows having members named the same as classes for a start. It will make parsing more complex indeed, but it is nothing new for C#. Every second language feature causes this.

Comment: @Athari you are absolutely right, it can be seen as a method call and I missed that point, but all I wanna say is, this syntax makes much more scenes, at least for programmers familiar with **c/c++**. Any how personally I think you answer is far better than mine and the best answer amongst others.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax

```
((Elephant) animal).UseTrunk();
```

comes from C, C++. The new C# possibilities are **is** and **as**.
If `Elephant` is a *class*, not *struct* the most accurate cast, IMHO, is

```
  Elephant elephant = animal as Elephant;

  if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(null, elephant))
    elephant.UseTrunk();
  else {
    // animal isn't an elephant - do nothing, throw exception etc.
  }
```

But often (if you're *quite sure* that `animal` is fact an `Elephant`) you can simply put

```
  (animal as Elephant).UseTrunk(); // <- Not recommended, see Athari's comment
```

If `Elephant` is a *struct*, in the most accurate case you have to do something like

```
  // Drawback: you have to cast twice
  if (animal is Elephant) // <- 1st cast
    ((Elephant) animal).UseTrunk(); // <- 2nd cast
```

Comment: `(animal as Elephant).UseTrunk()` syntax should never be used. If `animal` is not `Elephant`, `(Elephant)animal` will cause a relatively detailed cast exception, while the code above will cause null reference exception. It makes a huge difference in complex expressions, but even in simple expressions a cast exception is more appropriate.

Comment: @Athari: Within `Foo<T,U> where T:class`, given `T myT; U myU;` I believe the compiler will allow `myT = myU as T`, but not `(T)myU`.  A runtime-type-checked direct conversion might be nicer than an `as` typecast which may return `null`, but I don't know a syntax for that.

Answer (score 3):

`((Elephant)animal).UseTrunk()` comes from C++ from which C# is derived.

C++ also has functional syntax `Elephant(animal).UseTrunk()`, but C# language designers decided to not support it. The reason is that it provides very few benefits while complicating logic for name resolving. Well-designed programs shouldn't use type casting a lot, so this isn't a problem.

You can simplify your code by using the following extension method:

```
    public static T To<T> (this object @this)
    {
        return (T)@this;
    }
```

Your example becomes `animal.To<Elephant>().UseTrunk()` which is pretty close to the syntax you propose.

Comment: Having a close-parenthesis mark the end of the thing being converted is IMHO much cleaner than relying upon operator precedence.  I wonder if `(type:value)` would have posed any problems as a syntax?  Unless `?:` is usable with types [which would be rather weird] the `:` couldn't parse as anything other than a type/value separator.

Answer (score 2):

As others have noted, this prefix cast syntax goes back at least to the C language, predating object oriented programming by quite some time.

If it was a postfix operator, as in your example, it would be harder to for the parser to distinguish it from function calls. Prefix parentheses weren't already in use.

It really does boil down to "we need a syntax, this one is easy to implement and not painfully ugly, go for it."

Answer (score 1):

There is `(animal as Elephant).UseTrunk()`, same ordering and same number of parentheses. But I still prefer the regular casting. It comes from C or even earlier, so yes, historical reasons.

Comment: The syntax "animal as Elephant" is OK providing that Elephant is a class, not struct

Answer (score 1):

I do find what you propose a little more concise, it can save a few keystrokes. But it can be confusing when it comes to methods. Take a few comparisons of worst cases:

```
var i = (int)Get(); //existing syntax
var i = Get()(int); //what you propose

var i = (int)Get<int>(typeof(int)); //existing syntax
var i = Get<int>(typeof(int))(int); //what you propose

var i = ((Mammoth)(Elephant)Get()).Trunk; //existing syntax
var i = Get()(Elephant)(Mammoth).Trunk; //what you propose

var i = ((Mammoth)((Elephant)Get()).Trunk).Trunk; //existing syntax
var i = Get()(Elephant).Trunk(Mammoth).Trunk; //what you propose
```

To each his own in the end. Languages like python has a more forward style approach, for instance:

```
i = int(animal);
```

but that's not technically `cast` operator.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't it more logical to have `animal(Elephant).UseTrunk()`.

That syntax is already used by C# (and C, from whence it came). It means, "Call the function `animal`, passing in `Elephant` as an argument. Then call `UseTrunk()` on the result of that."

If you also allowed that syntax as a type coercion, you'd have to figure out some way to disambiguate the two. One way to tweak the syntax would be like so:

```
animal.(Elephant).UseTrack()
```

The `.(` makes it unambiguous since that syntax is not currently being used for anything. And, indeed, this is exactly the syntax choice Go made for type coercions.

Answer (score 0):

Because not every animal have `useTrunk()` but it should be a special method for an elephant. Let's say every animal has `walk()`, so you can just use animal().walk(), but you can't call animal().useTrunk() unless you can confirm that this class can be cast (this animal absolutely) to an `elephant`. I think this is the basic idea of Object Oriented.

Comment: I am not talking about the concept of casting in general - I'm talking about the syntax.

Comment: Well, I agree with you, this looks also not that clean to me. But it seems the syntax is coming from the earlier C type cast I suppose...